# Return a Scrolling Div to Top

Tags: html, overflow

I have a div that animates over a picture on hover. The content in the div occasionally becomes too large for the div so I set the div to overflow: scroll. Is there a way to have the scrolling div reset to the top when a user stops hovering and then hovers again?

```
<figcaption class="figure" align="center" style="width: 92%; height: 95%; overflow: scroll;  padding-right: 12px;">
            <h2>The Exiled Queen</h3>
            <p>Han is a wizard and must learn how to use his gift of magic at the school of Oden's Ford.</p> 
            <p>Meanwhile, Princess Heir, Raisa ana'Marianna, is fleeing The Fells to escape an unwanted marriage. But where can she go to stay out of trouble?</p>  
</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="cap-bot">
            <img src="http://yabooks.ml/Images/The Gray Wolf Throne.jpeg" alt="" style="width: 95%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0.5%;">
            <figcaption class="figure" align="center" style="width: 92%; height: 95%; overflow: scroll; padding-right: 12px;">
            <h2>The Gray Wolf Throne</h3>
            <p>Raisa has escaped from her captor, Micah Bayar, and begun her journey back to the Fells. But when her entire guard is killed, she learns that a return to the Fells may create more problems than it solves.</p> 
            <p>Hans Halister desperately needs to find Rebecca Moreley, his friend from Oden's Ford. But when he finds her, hours from death in the Fells, he learns that she is not who she said she was. She is Raisa, ana'Marianna, princess heir to the Fells.</p>
            <p>But the Fells is dangerous place. When Queen Mariana turns up dead, Raisa knows that she has no choice but to claim the throne. But with danger closing in on her from all sides, she will need all the help she can get.</p>    
</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="cap-bot">
            <img src="http://yabooks.ml/Images/The Crimson Crown.jpeg" alt="" style="width: 95%; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 0.5%;">
            <figcaption class="figure" align="center" style="width: 92%; height: 95%; overflow: scroll; padding-right: 12px;">
            <h2>The Exiled Queen</h3>
            <p>Han is a wizard and must learn how to use his gift of magic at the school of Oden's Ford.</p> 
            <p>Meanwhile, Princess Heir, Raisa ana'Marianna, is fleeing The Fells to escape an unwanted marriage. But where can she go to stay out of trouble?</p>  
</figcaption>
</figure>
<style>
figure {
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
width: 80%;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-left: 10%
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
figcaption {
position: absolute;
background: black;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
color: white;
padding: 10px 10px;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
-moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
-o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 5px;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
opacity: 1;
}
figure:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
font-weight: 800;
background: black;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
text-shadow: 0 0 5px white;
color: black;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius:    12px;
border-radius:         12px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 24px;
-moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
opacity: 0.75;
}
figure:hover:before {
opacity: 0;
}

.cap-left:before {  bottom: 10px; left: 10px; }
.cap-left figcaption { bottom: 0; left: -30%; }
.cap-left:hover figcaption { left: 0; }

.cap-right:before { bottom: 10px; right: 10px; }
.cap-right figcaption { bottom: 0; right: -30%; }
.cap-right:hover figcaption { right: 0; }

.cap-top:before { top: 10px; left: 10px; }
.cap-top figcaption { left: 0; top: -30%; }
.cap-top:hover figcaption { top: 0; }

.cap-bot:before { bottom: 10px; left: 10px; }
.cap-bot figcaption { left: 0; bottom: -30%;}
.cap-bot:hover figcaption { bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: Suggestions: 1. make a fiddle. 2. you can use javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the scrollTop of that div to 0.

```
$('#content').scrollTop(0);
```

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/donnellyjoe/Lktwg16h/

Answer (score 1):

### Handling scroll event

jquery:

```
$('#content').hover( function() {
    // mouse over code
}, function() {
    // mouse out code
});
```

native js:

```
var item = document.getElementById("content");
item.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    // mouse over code
}, false);
item.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    // mouse out code
}, false);
```

### Setting the scroll position

jquery:

```
$('#content').scrollTop(0);
```

native js:

```
document.getElementById('content').scrollTop = 0;
```

Without more information about what you need these are all the pieces that you should need to accomplish the feature you are working on.